# Alternative to an each block to avoid printing header for each instance of a subcategory?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been given an assignment: there's a static webpage that contains information that has been manually written in the view. I'm supposed to move that info into a database so we can clear out the view. My problem is that I don't know how to print that information in the exact same format the page currently has.

What I'm trying to do is write a method that returns information like this (original format example):

```
<strong>Category1</strong>
<ul class="square_list">
<li>Item1</li>
<li>Item2</li>
 #...etc
</ul>

<strong>Category2</strong>
<ul class="square_list">
<li>Item1</li>
<li>Item2</li>
 #...etc
</ul>

#...etc
```

The *closest* I'm able to get with my own limited knowledge is this:

```
<% Bus.find(10).amenities.each do | amenity | %>
    <strong><%= amenity.category %></strong>
    <ul class="square_list">
    <li><%= amenity.item %></li>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

Which prints out the category name above each instance of an item. Is there a way to make an each block do what I want it to or is there another method I ought to be using?

As requested, model info:

```
class Bus < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :bus_amenities
has_many :amenities, :through => :bus_amenities

class BusAmenity < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :bus
belongs_to :amenity

class Amenity < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :bus_amenities
has_many :buses, :through => :bus_amenities
```

Amenity(category: string, item: string)
BusAmenity just acts as a go-between for Buses and Amenities.

This app uses Rails 3.0.19 and Ruby 1.9.3p327.

If I haven't provided enough information let me know please.

Comment: Please provide more info. Like the relation b/w Bus, Amenity and item.

Comment: Edited original post, will add even more if requested!

Answer (score 1):

What you have looks perfectly workable, except that your `amenity` has a singular `item`. If instead it's a collection of `items` then your template can be modified slightly to match the original:

```
<% Bus.find(10).amenities.each do | amenity | %>
    <strong><%= amenity.category %></strong>
    <ul class="square_list">
    <% amenity.items.each do |item| %>
      <li><%= item %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>   
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm getting back a `undefined method 'items` error with this.

Comment: @RyanClark, if there aren't already multiple items associated with an amenity then you either need to add that association, or find some other way to associate each category with multiple items.

Comment: Do you mean that I should try splitting off items into a separate table? Thanks for your advice!

Comment: @RyanClark, yes, the ordinary way to handle a one-to-many relationship is to normalize the attributes into separate tables. Then in Rails, Amenity `has_many :items` and AmenityItem `belongs_to :amenity`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that does what I wanted, but it seems pretty lousy. I'm sure there's a better solution out there.

So this does what I want, but it seems so wordy to have to write an each block out for every category.

```
<strong>Category1</strong>
 <% Bus.find(10).amenities.find(:all, :conditions => {:category => "category1" }).each do | amenity | %>
  <ul class="square_list">
   <li><%= amenity.item %></li>
  </ul>
 <% end %>

<strong>Category2</strong>
 <% Bus.find(10).amenities.find(:all, :conditions => {:category => "category2" }).each do | amenity | %>  
  <ul class="square_list">
   <li><%= amenity.item %></li>
  </ul>
 <% end %>
```